# ListView - EditItemTemplate & InsertItemTemplate

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, webforms

I don't have direct access to my codebase at the moment, but hopefully I can demonstrate my question adequately without posting my actual code.

To set the scene, I have a rather long and ungainly multi-page "booking form" control that uses a MultiView, with a View for each page. I am trying to refactor this to tidy it up and make it more readable (although I need to keep it within one control). Within one particular View, I have a ListView, which can be used to add an arbitrary number of additional people to the booking. The ListView is bound manually to a `List<Person>` (via `OnItemUpdating` and `OnItemInserting` events), which is a member of the overall `Booking` object.

My ListView has an EditItemTemplate and an InsertItemTemplate. These are almost identical to each other, except for the fact that the EditItemTemplate has some additional information about the existing item at the top:

```
<EditItemTemplate>
    <div class="ItemInfo">
        <!-- Controls a & b -->
    </div>
    <div class="FormControls">
        <!-- Controls c, d, & e -->
    </div>
</EditItemTemplate>

<InsertItemTemplate>
    <div class="FormControls">
        <!-- Controls c, d, & e -->
    </div>
</InsertItemTemplate>
```

What I would like to be able to do is base one of these templates on the other, which will allow me to remove around 300 lines of redundant markup. I am, however, still restricted to the use of one standalone control. I have seen examples of similar situations that have been addressed like this:

```
protected void lvPeople_Init(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lvPeople.InsertItemTemplate = lvPeople.EditItemTemplate;
}
```

The problem here is that this will also put controls 'a' and 'b' into the InsertItemTemplate. 'a' and 'b' contain information that does not yet exist for newly-added items. I could enter default values, but this is undesirable as the form will be multi-lingual and this will mean unnecessary extra work for content editors - it is preferable that these controls are exclusive to the EditItemTemplate.

Is there a neat way of handling this without the use of an additional control?

Thanks.